# How i can click a button below a text using Selenium lib. in Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I want to build a bot that likes the comments in a web page. There is an like and dislike button below the comment.

xPath of the comment : `//*[@id="commentText-40538697"]/span`

xPath of the like button:

```
//*[@id="commentText-40538697"]/div[2]/div[1]/label[1]
```

As you can see if i get the comment id (in above example it is 40538697) i can easly click the button. Button the id is changing for each comment. So i get the element using below code

xpath=`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'COMMENT')]")`

-- Also the property of the taken element.

xpath.get_property
Out[113]: >

Is there any way to get div id of a specific text in a web page ?

Comment: Can you please share DOM or URL ?

Comment: Sure, https://tr.investing.com/equities/bim-magazalar-commentary

Comment: that is the site i am trying to like the comments.  you can select one of them as an example

Comment: so you want to extract comments ?

Comment: your comment id is dynamic and you cant extract element with ("//*[contains(text(), 'COMMENT')]")

Comment: no i do not want to extract comments. I want to determine some comments with keywords then i want to click like button below those comments.

Comment: yess my comment id is dynamic, how i can determine it

Comment: i tried to find the dynamic id with the following code id=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Comment key words')]").get_property('id') but it returns null :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try below xpath to extract comment based on keywords. Also you can use following sibling to check presence of show more and click on it

```
YourText="Fikrini empoze"

//div[@class='js-comments-wrapper commentsWrapper']//div[@class="comment js-comment"]//div[@class="js-text-wrapper commentText"][contains(.,'"+YourText+"')]
```

**show More Text**

```
//div[@class='js-comments-wrapper commentsWrapper']//div[@class="comment js-comment"]//div[@class="js-text-wrapper commentText"][contains(.,'Fikrini empoze')]//following-sibling::span[@class='showMoreText']
```

**like button:**

```
//div[@class='js-comments-wrapper commentsWrapper']//div[@class="comment js-comment"]//div[@class="js-text-wrapper commentText"][contains(.,' Fikrini empoze')]//following-sibling::label[@class='like']
```

**dislike**

```
//div[@class='js-comments-wrapper commentsWrapper']//div[@class="comment js-comment"]//div[@class="js-text-wrapper commentText"][contains(.,' Fikrini empoze')]//following-sibling::label[@class='dislike']
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, if i wrote this can i reach the like button of the comment. YourText="Fikrini empoze"

//div[@class='js-comments-wrapper commentsWrapper']//div[@class="comment js-comment"]//div[@class="js-text-wrapper commentText"][contains(.,'"+YourText+"')]//div[@class="commentButtons js-not-master-user"]//div[@class="inlineblock likeDislikeBox js-like-dislike-box"]//div[@class="like"]

Comment: once you confirmed then would you kind enough to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer